# Connect to internet via internet cafe PC when no wi-fi or 3G is available?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, internet, reverse-tether

We are developing an Android data-entry application for use in places with very limited connectivity.  We'll be using old/discarded Android devices in areas outside towns in Kenya, Uganda, etc. where there is no wi-fi; the devices themselves are not signed to a phone service.  Users collect data in the field & return home, where typically internet access is available only via shared PCs at internet cafes.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to connect an Android phone to a PC via the USB cable such that it shares the PC's internet connection for outbound connections?  ie. reverse tethering...  which seems to be a common topic, but all of the solutions seem to involve installing software on the PC, which I'm not sure would work at a cafe.  Is there "an app for that"?

I can provide more details if it helps find a solution!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No; a device-side app can't force the PC to share its internet connection.

One option might be to connect the device and mount the storage to the PC, so the data could be uploaded to a website or emailed.  This has its own issues -- depending on the PC OS and the particular phone, drivers might be needed -- but it should work in some cases.